# Save all the spans associated with a Spannable?

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable

I use a Spannable + EditText to create a RichText Editor.

I have already implemented the Editor.

Now I need to save the content to a file
(Don't tell me the html method)

So I plan to save the plain text separately and all the Spans separately.

How do I do this?

I'm not sure whether I should save all the spans.
Is it sufficient to first get them all using getSpan and then SetSpan them all. I mean is there a loss of information/details though I recreate all the spans?

Comment: see `TextUtils#writeToParcel`, note that Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism though

Comment: and it seems that this is your 4th question of "how to serialize Spannable object", i already gave you the **working solution**, so please do not open another one or it will be immediately closed